# Image not uploading to server and database

Tags: java, php, android

I'm working on uploading multiple images. I can pick an image from my phone's sd card but when I'm trying to upload it to my database, the progress dialog shows "Uploading" only and after that it is being dismissed. Honestly, I'm not sure on my php code. Hope someone can help me :)

Here's my uploadActivity.java:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private Button upload, pick;
private ProgressDialog dialog;
MultipartEntity entity;
GridView gv;
int count = 0;
public ArrayList<String> map = new ArrayList<String>();
Bundle b;
TextView noImage;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    b = getIntent().getExtras();

    noImage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noImage);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    pick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPicture);
    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    if (b != null) {
        ArrayList<String> ImgData = b.getStringArrayList("IMAGE");
        for (int i = 0; i < ImgData.size(); i++) {
            map.add(ImgData.get(i).toString());
        }
    } else {
        noImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new ImageUploadTask()
                    .execute(count + "", "pk" + count + ".jpg");
        }
    });

    pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
            startActivity(i3);
        }
    });

}

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String sResponse = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading",
                "Please wait...", true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url = "http://iguideph-001-btempurl.com/uploads.php";
            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("199"));
            entity.addPart("club_id", new StringBody("10"));
            entity.addPart("club_image", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "image/jpeg", params[1]));

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                    localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

            if (sResponse != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        sResponse + " Photo uploaded successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                count++;
                if (count < map.size()) {
                    new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
                            + ".jpg");
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);
    return bitmap;
}

private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return map.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
            // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85,
                    Gravity.CENTER));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView
                .setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(map.get(position)));

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

}

and here's my uploads.php:

```
<?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ 
 $image = $_POST['club_image'];
 $userid=$_POST['user_id'];
 $clubid=$_POST['club_id'];
 require_once('connection.php');
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id ASC";
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $id = 0;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 $id = $row['id'];
 }
 $path = "uploads/$id.jpg";
 $actualpath = "http://iguideph-001-site1.btempurl.com/PhotoUpload/$path";    
 $sql = "INSERT INTO photos (image) VALUES ('$actualpath')";

 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
 echo "Successfully Uploaded";
 }

  mysqli_close($con);
  }else{
  echo "Error";
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: `$_POST['club_image']` => `$_FILES['club_image']` we're dealing with files here and not text input. I can't help with your java but check for errors via FTP http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and your sql http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - Plus, files require a valid enctype if you're not already using one.

Comment: Thanks @Fred . Let me try this :)

Comment: you're welcome. hope it works for you.

Comment: I havent made it yet sir. I have hard time in creating my php code. Hope you can help me sir :) Can i email you ? Thanks :)